# keep getting "TypeError: 'int' object is not callable"

Tags: python, int

I keep getting the same error and i dont know why, i am new to python and am trying out a little project to guess random numbers! Here is my code:

```
import random

number_guess = int(input("Enter a random number between 1 - 100 please!"))
random_number = random.randrange(0,100)

if number_guess == random_number():
    print("Correct! The number was " + random_number + "!")
else:
    print("Wrong! The real number was " + random_number + "!")
```

Comment: Remove the parentheses `()` after `random_number`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As leaf stated one error here is that in your if statement you have random_number() you are calling a variable and not a method, you should remove the parenthesis.

Another problem being though is that you are attempting to add an int to a String and that cannot be done, on the print statements you should replace the '+' with commas and you program will run perfectly as intended!

As well as if you actually want values of 1 to 100 you should set the starting number to one as if it is set to 0 you have the chance to get a 0, and if you have the max value set to 100 you will never get a value greater than 99, meaning a guess of 100 will never be correct.

So your final project should look like:

```
import random

number_guess = int(input("Enter a random number between 1 - 100 please! "))
random_number = random.randrange(1,101)

if number_guess == random_number:
    print("Correct! The number was ", random_number, "!")
else:
    print("Wrong! The real number was ", random_number, "!")
```

Answer (score 1):

`random.randrange()` returns a random integer between a specified range. [The documentation states this quit clearly](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#randrange):

> `random.randrange(start, stop[, step])`
>
> Return a randomly selected element from range`(start, stop, step)`. This is equivalent to choice`(range(start, stop, step))`, but doesn’t actually build a range object.

The value then of `random_number` is of type `int`, **which is not callable**. In you if statement, there is no need for parenthesis. Simply write `random_number` without the pair of parenthesis.